# Conditions for NFA universality

Tags: automata-theory, fl.formal-languages, nondeterminism

Consider a nondeterministic finite automata $A = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$, and a function $f(n)$. Additionally we define $\Sigma^{\leq k} = \bigcup_{i \leq k} \Sigma^i$.

Now lets analyze the following statement:

> If $\Sigma^{\leq f(|Q|)} \subseteq L(A)$, then $L(A) = \Sigma^*$.

It is easy to show, that for $f(n) = 2^n+1$ it is true, hence if the automata produces every word with length upto $2^{|Q|}+1$, then it produces $\Sigma^*$.

But does it still hold if $f$ is a polynom?

If not, what could a construction of a NFA $A$ for a given polynom $p$ look like, s.t. $\Sigma^{\leq p(|Q|)} \subseteq L(A) \subsetneq \Sigma^*$?

Comment: I would like to give the bounty to a proof or disproof that $f(n)=2^{n−o(n)}$ for the case $|\Sigma|\geq 2$. And if there is none, I'll give it to the best construction one can get.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the statement to hold, *f* must grow exponentially, even with the unary alphabet.

*[Edit: The analysis is improved slightly in revision 2.]*

Here is a proof sketch.  Suppose that the statement holds and let *f* be a function such that every NFA with at most *n* states that accepts all strings with length at most *f*(*n*) accepts all strings whatsoever.  We will prove that for every *C*>0 and sufficiently large *n*, we have *f*(*n*) > 2<sup>*C*⋅√*n*</sup>.

The [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) implies that for every *c* < lg e and for sufficiently large *k*, there are at least *c* ⋅2<sup>*k*</sup> / *k* primes in the range [2<sup>*k*</sup>, 2<sup>*k*+1</sup>].  We take *c*=1.  For such *k*, let *N*<sub>*k*</sub> = ⌈2<sup>*k*</sup> / *k*⌉ and define an NFA *M*<sub>*k*</sub> as follows.  Let *p*<sub>1</sub>, …, *p*<sub>*N*<sub>*k*</sub></sub> be distinct primes in the range [2<sup>*k*</sup>, 2<sup>*k*+1</sup>].  The NFA *M*<sub>*k*</sub> has *S*<sub>*k*</sub>=1+*p*<sub>1</sub>+…+*p*<sub>*N*<sub>*k*</sub></sub> states.  Apart from the initial state, the states are partitioned into *N*<sub>*k*</sub> cycles where the *i*th cycle has length *p*<sub>*i*</sub>.  In each cycle, all but one state are accepted states.  The initial state has *N*<sub>*k*</sub> outgoing edges, each of which goes to the state immediately after the rejected state in each cycle.  Finally, the initial state is also accepted.

Let *P*<sub>*k*</sub> be the product *p*<sub>1</sub>…*p*<sub>*N*<sub>*k*</sub></sub>.  It is easy to see that *M*<sub>*k*</sub> accepts all strings of length less than *P*<sub>*k*</sub> but rejects the string of length *P*<sub>*k*</sub>.  Therefore, *f*(*S*<sub>*k*</sub>)≥*P*<sub>*k*</sub>.

Note that *S*<sub>*k*</sub> ≤ 1 + *N*<sub>*k*</sub>⋅2<sup>*k*+1</sup> = o(2<sup>2*k*</sup>) and that *P*<sub>*k*</sub> ≥ (2<sup>*k*</sup>)<sup>*N*<sub>*k*</sub></sup> ≥ 2<sup>2<sup>*k*</sup></sup>.  The rest is standard.

Comment: What is your conjecture about the best value of $f$? Say $f(n) = 2^n+1$, or somewhere between $2^n$ and $2^{c\cdot\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: @Hsien-Chih: I was wondering the same thing, and I do not have any reasonable conjecture.  First, it is trivial to see f(n)≤2^n (we do not need +1) and, while I expect some linear improvement over this upper bound, I have no idea whether it is tight up to a constant factor.  (more)

Comment: (cont’d)  Second, as for the lower bound, if I am not mistaken, a slight refinement of the above analysis gives the following lower bound: for every constant 0 < c < $1/\sqrt2$ and sufficiently large n, we have $f(n) > e^{c\sqrt{n \ln n}}$.  Further refinements are probably possible, but we cannot obtain a lower bound such as 2^{n^p} for p>1/2 if we use the same construction of the NTM.  I think that it is an interesting question whether the use of the distribution of primes (such as the PNT) is essential for a construction of bad examples.  (more)

Comment: (cont’d)  However, if you are interested and want to investigate it further, probably it is wiser to look for the literature first.  I will not be surprised if this answer or something better has already appeared in the literature.

Comment: Oops, I should have written $f(n) \le 2^n-1$ in my first comment.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: It is shown by Chrobak that an n-state DFA for an unary language can be simulated by an m-state NFA for $m=O(e^{\sqrt{n\log n}})$. Thus your construction is tight if the language is unary. See [Chr86]: http://www.cs.ust.hk/mjg_lib/Library/Chro86.pdf

Comment: @Hsien-Chih: Thanks for the reference!  Actually, it seems that it is possible to combine the construction in the paper and the construction in this answer to get a tighter lower bound.  If you or anyone else wants to do this, please feel free to post it as a separate answer.  If no one does this, I will try to update my answer in a few days.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Do you mean by combining your answer to [Chr86], or the work by Shallit? I'm pretty amazed if it is the latter case.

Comment: @Hsien-Chih: What I meant was modifying the construction in the proof of Theorem 4.5 in [Chr86] slightly for this problem (“combining” with my answer was an overstatement).

Answer (score 21):

### EDIT AT 10/12/06:

ok, this is pretty much the best construction I can get, see if any one come up with better ideas.

> **Theorem.** For each $n$ There is an $(5n+12)$-state NFA $M$ over alphabets $\Sigma$ with $|\Sigma|=5$ such that the shortest string not in $L(M)$ is of length $(2^n-1)(n+1)+1$.

This will give us $f(n) = \Omega(2^{n/5})$.

The construction is pretty much the same with the one in [Shallit's](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Talks/re.ps), except we construct an NFA directly instead of representing the language by a regular expression first. Let

$\Sigma = \{{0 \brack 0},{0 \brack 1},{1 \brack 0},{1 \brack 1},\sharp\}$.

For each $n$, we are going to construct an NFA recognizing language $\Sigma^*-\{s_n\}$, where $s_n$ is the following sequence (take $n=3$ for example):

$s_3 = \sharp{0 \brack 0}{0 \brack 0}{0 \brack 1}\sharp{0 \brack 0}{0 \brack 1}{1 \brack 0}\sharp \ldots \sharp{1 \brack 1}{1 \brack 1}{0 \brack 1}\sharp$.

The idea is that we can construct an NFA consists of five parts;

- a *starter*, which ensures the string starts with $\sharp{0 \brack 0}{0 \brack 0}{0 \brack 1}\sharp$;
- a *terminator*, which ensures the string ends with $\sharp{1 \brack 1}{1 \brack 1}{0 \brack 1}\sharp$;
- a *counter*, which keeps the number of symbols between two $\sharp$'s as $n$;
- an *add-one checker*, which guarantees that only symbols with the form $\sharp{x \atop x+1}\sharp$ appears; finally,
- a *consistent checker*, which guarantees that only symbols with the form $\sharp{x \atop y}\sharp{y \atop z}\sharp$ can appear concurrently.

Note that we do want to accept $\Sigma^*-\{s_n\}$ instead of $\{s_n\}$, so once we find out that the input sequence is disobeying one of the above behaviors, we accept the sequence immediately. Otherwise after $|s_n|$ steps, the NFA will be in the only possible rejecting state. And if the sequence is longer than $|s_n|$, the NFA also accepts. So any NFA satisfies the above five conditions will only reject $s_n$.

It may be easy to check the following figure directly instead of a rigorous proof:

[image: NFA for rejecting s_n]

We start at the upper-left state. The first part is the starter, and the counter, then the consistent checker, the terminator, finally the add-one checker. All the arc with no terminal nodes point to the bottom-right state, which is an all time acceptor. Some of the edges are not labeled due to lack of spaces, but they can be recovered easily. A dash line represents a sequence of $n-1$ states with $n-2$ edges.

We can (painfully) verify that the NFA rejects $s_n$ only, since it follows all the five rules above. So a $(5n+12)$-state NFA with $|\Sigma|=5$ has been constructed, which satisfies the requirement of the theorem.

If there's any unclearliness/problem with the construction, please leave a comment and I'll try to explain/fix it.

---

This question has been studied by [Jeffrey O. Shallit](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/) et al., and indeed the optimal value of $f(n)$ is still open for $|\Sigma|>1$. (As for unary language, see the comments in [Tsuyoshi's answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/conditions-for-nfa-universality/3502#3502))

In page 46-51 of [his talk on universality](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Talks/re.ps), he provided a construction such that:

> **Theorem.** For $n\geq N$ for some $N$ large enough, there is an $n$-state NFA $M$ over binary alphabets such that the shortest string not in $L(M)$ is of length $\Omega(2^{cn})$ for $c=1/75$.

Thus the optimal value for $f(n)$ is somewhere between $2^{n/75}$ and $2^n$. I'm not sure if the result by Shallit has been improved in recent years.

Comment: I'm playing with Shallit's work, hope to get a better bound much near $2^n$. Their construction seems interesting, by specify some sequence of length $\hat{\Omega}(2^n)$ which can not be represent by a "short" regular expression of length $cn+o(n)$, and each regular expression of length $f(n)$ can be described by an NFA of size $f(n)+1$. Currently I'm able to let $c \leq 22$, but a smarter idea is need to come close $2^n$.

Comment: I don't think it gives further insights for studying this problem, but the proper scholarly reference for Shallit's talk is: K. Ellul, B. Krawetz, J. Shallit, M. Wang: Regular Expressions: New Results and Open Problems. Journal of Automata, Languages and Combinatorics 10(4): 407-437 (2005)

Comment: @Hermann: Thank you for the reference, currently I cannot access to the paper, but I will find a way to.

Comment: I think by using *counter* we can replace the *starter* and *terminator* by a 2-state tiny machine. So this further reduce the size of NFA to $3n+O(1)$.

Comment: The author's preprint version of the noted JALC paper is here: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/re3.pdf The bound, and the proof is the same in the printed version.